# How to select words of the same CHAR_LENGTH in MySQL-PHP?

Tags: mysql

In order to use in a multiple choice test on Chinese Language, I need to select 5 words, all of them must have the same number of characters, one for the question, four for options. What I have been doing is:

```
SELECT hanzi, CHAR_LENGTH(hanzi) chlen FROM wordlist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

From here I get chlen to use it in another statement:

```
SELECT hanzi FROM wordlist WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(hanzi)=$chlen ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Can I do this using only one statement?

Comment: There is also another condition in the 2nd statement that the question word is not in those four words. I skipped it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery to achieve this:

```
SELECT hanzi FROM wordlist WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(hanzi) in (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(hanzi) chlen FROM wordlist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

I haven't tested it, so it might give some errors; but at least you can get a idea from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY length(column);
```

**Ref**

Documentation on the length() function, as well as all the other string functions, is available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length).

Comment: I guess Chinese would involve multibyte characters so char_length is ideal for this as length counts each character but char_length counts multibyte characters as one character